# Custom XHR not returning JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a small utility tool of sorts for the museum where I work. The Danish cultural ministry has a database, REGIN, where I can access various information about museum items in JSON. It is cross domain, with no callback. Now, there is an API for accessing the data, and I figured out how to access the item part of the database, so I can pick information about specific museum items.

Here's my problem: These items are arranged in various "view lists" or "collections", that are put together elsewhere. I am supposed to be able to access a JSON list of all the "collections" associated to my museum, which has an id of 229.
The URL is https://www.kulturarv.dk/regin/dapi/ListView?&viewType=viewList&format=json&museumId=229
When I access it normally in the browser, sure enough, there's the relevant information about the museums "views" in JSON.

```
[
{ "viewId" : "778","OprettetAfId" : "6813","OprettetDato" : "2011-06-20","name" : "Sølv test","keyword" : "test","text" : "Test af genstand for "skab 8"","museumId" : "229" },
{ "viewId" : "779","OprettetAfId" : "6813","OprettetDato" : "2011-06-22","name" : "Rum 29 - Skab 3","keyword" : "Test, drikkekrus, porcelæn","text" : "Genstande til Bibliotekssalens mobil-udstilling, skab 3.","museumId" : "229" },
{ "viewId" : "786","OprettetAfId" : "6813","OprettetDato" : "2011-09-02","name" : "genstand3skab3","keyword" : "til skab 3","text" : "Kærlighedsguden Amor","museumId" : "229" },
{ "viewId" : "792","OprettetAfId" : "6813","OprettetDato" : "2011-10-10","name" : "Skab 3 Bibliotekssalen","keyword" : "Porcelæn","text" : "Skab 3","museumId" : "229" },
{ "viewId" : "793","OprettetAfId" : "6813","OprettetDato" : "2011-10-13","name" : "genstand2skab3","keyword" : "til skab 3","text" : "Fugtbarhedsgudinden Ceres, skab 3","museumId" : "229" }
]
```

Now, for reasons I dont know, the same procedure that I use to access information about specific items doesnt allow me to open the beforementioned URL. Here is my code for accessing the above JSON, which returns nothing whatsoever:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    xmlhttp = new XSiteHttpRequest(); //a custom XHR... not sure why they decided to do it that way

    xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.kulturarv.dk/regin/dapi/ListView?&viewType=viewList&format=json&museumId=229",true);
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
       if (xmlhttp.status!=404) {
        alert("Works!");
       } 
       else {
        alert("Does not work!");
       };
      };
     };
     xmlhttp.send(null);

    });
```

Now, I assume that since I get no alert("Works!") OR alert("Does not work!") I am doing something wrong.

The same procedure worked with this URL:
https://www.kulturarv.dk/regin/dapi/ListView?viewType=objectContent&format=xml&objectType=Genstand&objectId=3911238

And this code gives the proper alert:

```
var objectId = 3911238;

$(document).ready(function() { 
xmlhttp = new XSiteHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.kulturarv.dk/regin/dapi/ListView?viewType=objectContent&format=json&objectType=Genstand&objectId=" + objectId,true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
   if (xmlhttp.status!=404) {
    alert("Works!");
   } 
   else {
    alert("Does not work!");
   };
  };
 };
 xmlhttp.send(null);

});
```

I can see no difference between the two, so what might be going on here?

I ran the non-working code through Firefox and the error consol said "unterminated string literal". Not sure what that means.

Comment: The developers write that it's a special object with the same API as XMLHttpRequest. I used it as XMLHttpRequest and it worked fine for my latter code example, but not the other... Link to their documentation: https://www.kulturarv.dk/regin-tools/pub/doc/devdoc/symbols/ReginDAPI.html